# dojo is it required to keep all the .js files

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, dojo, dojox.mobile

I am using dojo for UI in iPhone. I have copied dojo, dojox folders completely, 
and it takes huge amount of time compiling in Xcode.

It is OK if i keep only the required .js files?

For example

```
   require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dijit/registry", "dojox/mobile",  "dojox/mobile/SwapView", "dojox/mobile/TabBar",  "dojox/mobile/Button","dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojo/domReady!"],function(parser) {
                parser.parse();
            });
```

It is ok to include only the .js files respective to modules included above in the require function?

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep all of those files as well as all of the files that *they* depend upon and then the files that **they** depend on... dependencies all the way down.

Read up on the [Dojo Build System](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/). This will allow you to build a single file that only contains the Dojo files that you need and nothing else. It'll also minify it for you. This reduces the number of requests and the total amount of data sent when you pull in your JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any way we don't have to keep 'building' during development (where we may add,remove,change modules)? Or we are stuck back in square 1 at development time, to keep all files there?